# How to detect redundant edge in graph networkx python?

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I have a question, how can I detect and get the redundant value from graph connection? i already set the redundant graph connection in `add_edges_from()` like **(1,2)** and **(1,2)**. But when i print list of edges, it only detected as 1 connection. Here is my example:

```
test_graph = nx.Graph()
test_graph.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8), (6,8)])

posxx = nx.spring_layout(test_graph, scale = 1, k = 2 / np.sqrt(test_graph.order())) #planar -> no intersect
nx.draw(test_graph, posxx, node_color='red', font_size = 10, node_size = 350, with_labels=True)

list(test_graph.edges)
```

[image]

Output :

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)]
```

I want those redundant connection have output like integer number. Such as if i have
`(1,2),(1,2),(1,2)`, it is detected as 3 in edge value. Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphs with what you call "redundant" edges are typically called multigraphs.
In networkx, you can either (1) use the `MultiGraph` class to keep track of all edges individually, or (2) you can count the edges and then create a weighted `Graph`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from collections import Counter

edges = [
    (1, 2), (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 5),
    (5, 6),
    (6, 7),
    (6, 8),
    (7, 8),
]

# option 1: MultiGraph
g = nx.MultiGraph(edges)
print(g.edges)
 # MultiEdgeDataView([(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)])

# option 2: weighted Graph
edge_to_count = Counter(edges)
weighted_edges = [(source, target, {'weight' : count}) for (source, target), count in edge_to_count.items()]
g = nx.Graph(weighted_edges)

print(g.edges())
# EdgeView([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)])

g.get_edge_data(1, 2)
# {'weight': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, those weighted_edges part is the one i looking for my problem 